# Is there a way in the django views to make a css transform?

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-views

I am new to Django and trying to wrap my head around some stuff at the moment. I currently have a page that has a central card that when a button is clicked it flips the card all through CSS. I am now also redirecting the page back to its self in views.py is there a way to have the views redirect to the back of the card not the front. I know I could use java-script to achieve this but was wondering if there was a way with out.

views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views import View
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm



class login_register(View):

    def get(self, request):
        form = UserCreationForm()
        if "sign-in" in request.GET:
            username = request.GET.get("username")
            password = request.GET.get("password")
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/admin')
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'Login attempt failed.')
                return redirect('login_register')
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        if "sign-up" in request.POST:
            form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data['username']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, 'Account has been created succesfully')
                return redirect('login_register')
            else:
                messages.error(request, form.errors)
                return redirect('login_register')
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

HTML & CSS:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700,800,900');

body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #c4c3ca;
    background-color: #1f2029;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
a {
    cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.link {
  color: #c4c3ca;
}
.link:hover {
  color: #abf7b1;
}
p {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.7;
}
h4 {
  font-weight: 600;
}
h6 span{
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.section{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.full-height{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked){
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
.checkbox:checked + label,
.checkbox:not(:checked) + label{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #abf7b1;
}
.checkbox:checked + label:before,
.checkbox:not(:checked) + label:before{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #abf7b1;
  background-color: #102770;
  font-family: 'unicons';
  content: '\2196';
  z-index: 20;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.checkbox:checked + label:before {
  transform: translateX(44px) rotate(-270deg);
}


.card-3d-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 440px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 800px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.card-3d-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 600ms ease-out;
}
.card-front, .card-back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2a2b38;
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1462889/pat.svg');
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 300%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 6px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.checkbox:checked ~ .card-3d-wrap .card-3d-wrapper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.center-wrap{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 35px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 35px) perspective(100px);
  z-index: 20;
  display: block;
}


.form-group{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.form-style {
  padding: 13px 20px;
  padding-left: 55px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  outline: none;
  color: #c4c3ca;
  background-color: #1f2029;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(21,21,21,.2);
}
.form-style:focus,
.form-style:active {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(21,21,21,.2);
}
.input-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 18px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ffeba7;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.form-group input:-ms-input-placeholder  {
  color: #c4c3ca;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.form-group input::-moz-placeholder  {
  color: #c4c3ca;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.form-group input:-moz-placeholder  {
  color: #c4c3ca;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.form-group input::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
  color: #c4c3ca;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.form-group input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder  {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.form-group input:focus::-moz-placeholder  {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.form-group input:focus:-moz-placeholder  {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.form-group input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.form-group input:-webkit-autofill,
.form-group input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
.form-group input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
.form-group input:-webkit-autofill:active{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #1f2029 inset !important;
}

.btn{
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition : all 200ms linear;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  padding: 0 30px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: #abf7b1;
  color: #102770;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 24px 0 rgba(95,240,106,.2);
}
.btn:active,
.btn:focus{
  background-color: #102770;
  color: #abf7b1;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 24px 0 rgba(16,39,112,.2);
}
.btn:hover{
  background-color: #102770;
  color: #abf7b1;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 24px 0 rgba(16,39,112,.2);
}




.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: all 250ms linear;
}
.logo img {
    height: 26px;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
}

.alert {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Login/Register</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

        <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" />
        <link href="{% static 'css/login.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>


    <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row full-height justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-12 text-center align-self-center py-5">
                    <div class="section pb-5 pt-5 pt-sm-2 text-center">
                        <h6 class="mb-0 pb-3"><span>Log In </span><span>Sign Up</span></h6>
                        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="reg-log" name="reg-log"/>
                        <label for="reg-log"></label>
                        <div class="card-3d-wrap mx-auto">
                            <div class="card-3d-wrapper">
                                <div class="card-front">
                                    <div class="center-wrap">
                                        <div class="section text-center">
                                            {% if messages %}
                                                {% for message in messages %}
                                                    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                                                        {{ message }}
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                            <form action="" method="GET">
                                                {% csrf_token %}
                                                    <h4 class="mb-4 pb-3">Log In</h4>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-style" placeholder="Your Username" id="username" autocomplete="off">
                                                    <i class="input-icon uil uil-at"></i>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group mt-2">
                                                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-style" placeholder="Your Password" id="password" autocomplete="off">
                                                    <i class="input-icon uil uil-lock-alt"></i>
                                                </div>
                                                    <input type="submit" name="sign-in" value="Login" class="btn mt-4" >
                                                    <p class="mb-0 mt-4 text-center"><a href="#0" class="link">Forgot your password?</a></p>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-back">
                                    <div class="center-wrap">
                                        <div class="section text-center">
                                            {% if form.errors %}
                                                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                                                    There was an error with the form!
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                                </div>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if messages %}
                                                {% for message in messages %}
                                                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                                                        {{ message }}
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                            <form action="" method="POST">
                                                {% csrf_token %}
                                                <h4 class="mb-4 pb-3">Sign Up</h4>
                                                <div class="form-group mt-2">
                                                    {{ form }}
                                                </div>
                                                <input type="submit" name="sign-up" value="Register" class="btn mt-4" >
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `redirect()` to a `render()` (the same as in the `get()`) and then add a default value for the checkbox. If you want to keep the redirect, you can add a value in the session and again add in the get context.

For example:

```py
class login_register(View):
    def get(self, request):
        ...
        return render(
            request,
            'index.html',
            {
                'form': form,
                'using_backcard': request.session.pop('using_backcard', False),
            }
        )

    def post(self, request):
        if "sign-up" in request.POST:
            ...
                request.session['using_backcard'] = True
                return redirect('login_register')
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Then, in your template

```html
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="reg-log" name="reg-log" {% if using_backcard %} checked {% endif %}/>
```

Comment: This was the exact fix i needed I was having such a hard time wrapping my brain around this. Thank you.